# What platform to select for Facebook Messenger app review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

We're trying to submit a [messenger bot app to Facebook for review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/). The app is configured as live:

[image: App is configured as live]

It has some items as approved already:

[image: Approved items in Facebook]

And the platform on which it will operate is [messenger only](https://m.me/), however I do not see it listed here

[image: Facebook select platform]

What platform to select for Facebook Messenger app review?

Comment: You don't need to select any of these platforms; instead you need to add Messenger in the Products section of the app dashboard first. Configuration and submit for review happen from there.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks man! This is what we needed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[None of these...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812145/what-platform-to-select-for-facebook-messenger-app-review#comment80573864_46812145)**

To publish a bot on the Facebook the following stuff are required to be ready:

- **Icon**: You can upload a JPG, GIF or PNG file. The size of the image must be 1024 x 1024 pixels. File size limit 5 MB
- **App display name**
- **Contact Email** – In case if anyone (or Facebook) wants to contact a company
- **Category** – the business category for which bot is getting published
- **Privacy policy URL**
- **Terms of Service URL**
- **Video** - You'll be prompted to upload a screen-cast of your chat-bot working
- **Facebook page**

Most of the above stuff can be done with common sense and below is the actual review submission.

**Add messenger in Products if not already added**

[image: Add messenger in Products]

**Add permissions required by the app**

Go to the Messenger tab in the App Dashboard. Find the App Review section and select the permissions needed by the app.

[image: Messenger app permissions]

**Edit Notes for Each Submission**

After selecting the permissions, one can edit the notes for each submission. Click on <kbd>Edit Notes</kbd> for each permission. Make sure to fill each form and any other missing items before clicking <kbd>Submit for Review</kbd>.

[image: Edit Notes for Each Submission]

Facebook will need confirmation before submission:

[image: Facebook submission confirmation]

**Submit for Approval**

Once you've submitted your app, you can view the App Review section to see the status of your approval.

[image: Submit and Wait for Approval]

[image: Submission received]

**Approval**

Sometimes, the approval can be partial too:

[image: Partial Permission granted]

If the app submission is approved/rejected, Facebook sends a notification. Also, the App Review section will show the green ticks to approved permissions, if the permissions are granted.

[image: Approved permissions]

That's it.